# WordPress verify condition on custom post field when user click on "update the post"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently doing a wordpress project and I create a custom post. Inside this custom post, the admin can create posts and inside those posts he is able to set an id thanks to a custom_field. I would like to check that the id of each post is unique. 
I'm thinking about a "condition" when the user select "update" the post, I will check if the id is unique, if so I authorize the update if not I will display a popup to the admin explaining that the id he puts is not unique.
Is it possible to do it? How?

Comment: It is possible have a look at [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action hook

Comment: @RahilWazir ok it helps me. Do you know how to display pop up when the user click on "update the post" in the admin page with php?

Comment: This can be done via JavaScript.